# Laravel schedule not respecting time

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler, laravel-scheduler

I am using Laravel 9 and I am trying to set several tasks in my schedule.
One of them should be called every minutes the other every 5 minutes .

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
       $schedule->call(/* send myself a mail */)->everyMinute();
       $schedule->call(/* send myself a mail */)->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
```

On my host I have a cron task called every minutes :

```
/opt/alt/php81/usr/bin/php ~/my-path/artisan schedule:run
```

However every minutes I receive the mail from my `everyMinute()` task, and the mail from my `everyFiveMinutes()` task.

I tried with `job` and `command` instead of `call` but it doesn't changes anything, same with `->cron('* * * * *')`  instead of `->everyMinute()`

Comment: Are you running this Locally or remote?

Comment: I'm doing it remote

Comment: have you tried the command that laravel give? `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: This is whats I was using before, but it wasn't working and never calls my schedule

Comment: Do you have cron installed on your machine?

Comment: Your environment is ubuntu right?

Comment: I am using ubuntu, and the cron task is set a the server host of my website which is o2switch

Comment: I think the cron job is properly set as it correctly call my schedule every minutes. The problem is Laravel calling every scheduled call no matter the time I set.

Comment: try logging instead of sending the email?

Comment: Why would the content of my function called affect if it is call or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue.

I discover that when I use the schedule like this:

```
$schedule->call( MyController::MyFunction() )->everyFiveMinutes();
```

It run every minute, not every 5 minute as it would suppose to run.

If I run like this, every works as expect:

```
$schedule->call(function () {MyController::MyFunction();})->everyFiveMinutes();
```